# Multiple search parameters with LINQ

Tags: c#, linq-to-sql

I'm writing what I believe should be a relatively straight-forward Windows Form app. I'm using LINQ to SQL, though I have never used it before. We have a SQL Server database, and I'm creating a front-end to access that database. I'm trying to figure out the most efficient way to search for multiple (arbitrary number of) search parameters with it.

In the windows form, I create a dictionary with each search key and its value to search for, and pass it into my search() method. I am trying to find a way to search the database with each of those keys and their associated values. Here is what I am trying to do:

```
public IQueryable<Product> Search(Dictionary<string, string> searchParams)
{
   DBDataContext dc = new DBDataContext();
   var query = dc.Products;

   foreach (KeyValuePair<string, string> temp in searchParams)
   {
      query = query.Where(x => x.(temp.Key) == temp.Value);
   }

   return query;
}
```

I realize that syntactically x.(temp.Key) is incorrect, but I hope that illustrates what I am trying to do. I was wondering if there is another way to go about what I am trying to do without having to do a giant switch statement (or if/else if tree).

EDIT

So, I revised it a little, but I'm still having issues with it. Here is what I currently have:

```
public IQueryable<Product> Search(Dictionary<string, string> searchParams)
{
    DBDataContext dc = new DBDataContext();

    string sQuery = "";
    foreach (KeyValuePair<string, string> temp in searchParams)
    {
        sQuery += temp.Key + "=" + temp.Value + " AND ";
    }

    var query = dc.Products.Where(sQuery);

    return query;
}
```

According to the LINQ Dynamic Query Library article, this should be OK. Here is the error I'm getting:

The type arguments for method 'System.Linq.Queryable.Where(System.Linq.IQueryable, System.Linq.Expressions.Expression>)' cannot be inferred from the usage. Try specifying the type arguments explicitly.

Comment: Is there a reason that the Search method parameter needs to be a dictionary rather than a Func<Product, bool> ???

Comment: Not entirely sure what you mean by that... could you please clarify?

Comment: Each key in the dictionary contains the parameters to search for (and each parameters value to search for).

Comment: Per your dynamic query builder example, I added an edit regarding the "AND" at the end below, which will hopefully fix it for you.

Answer (score 3):

Here's an example that works (I just tested it), using the [Dynamic LINQ Query Library](http://weblogs.asp.net/scottgu/archive/2008/01/07/dynamic-linq-part-1-using-the-linq-dynamic-query-library.aspx).

```
using System.Linq.Dynamic;
// ...

Dictionary<string, string> searchParams = new Dictionary<string,string>();

searchParams.Add("EmployeeID", "78");
searchParams.Add("EmpType", "\"my emp type\"");

IQueryable<Employee> query = context.Employees;

foreach (KeyValuePair<string, string> keyValuePair in searchParams)
{
    query = query.Where(string.Format("{0} = {1}", keyValuePair.Key,  keyValuePair.Value));
}

List<Employee> employees = query.ToList();
```

And, to make it **absolutely clear** that this code **actually works** here is the **actual** generated SQL:

```
FROM [HumanResources].[Employee] AS [t0]
WHERE ([t0].[EmpType] = @p0) AND ([t0].[EmployeeID] = @p1)',N'@p0 nvarchar(11),@p1 int',@p0=N'my emp type',@p1=78
```

Comment: Well it finally compiles, so that's a huge first step. THANK YOU so much to you and Kevin Nelson. Different problem now: When I enter in a value to search for, an exception is thrown in the DynamicLibrary that no property or field [value I searched for] exists in 'Products'. So it seems that rather than searching for the value in each entry's key, it is searching each entry for a field which is the value I want to search for. If I'm searching for a first name, it is looking for Employee.jonathan = first_name, rather than Employee.first_name = jonathan.

Comment: I've tried switching the order of the query string to query = query.Where(string.Format("{0} = {1}", keyValuePair.Value, keyValuePair.Key)); and it still throws the same exception.

Comment: In the debugger, it seems that no matter the order of the key and value in the dictionary, DynamicLibrary always searches against the value, rather than the key.

Comment: Hmmm, it's hard to say without seeing your actual code.  Switching key and value won't help.  One strategy is to just temporarily hardcode your query string into the Where() to eliminate string building errors, and make sure it works that way first.  Like: query = query.Where("EmployeeID = 78"); and so on.

Comment: Also, you might want to use SQL Server Profiler to verify the generated SQL query.  IIRC, the VS debugger isn't able to show you the SQL when you're using Dynamic.

Comment: You're now open to all kinds of SQL injections. You don't escape values, you don't quote strings. The latter is probably the cause of exceptions. SELECT * FROM products WHERE name = tasty cake?

Comment: @Athari: Injections: **Dynamic LINQ processes the input string further to prevent injections.**  See the third comment by Scott Gu himself on the Dynamic LINQ page I linked to in my answer.  I have added the *actual* generated SQL to my answer.  **I tested and verified the code in my answer (I always do) and it works as I have suggested.**

Comment: @shaunmartin OK, sorry. Dynamic LINQ seems to be smarter than I thought. :) Still, it's like using a steam-hammer to crack nuts... I don't know why Jonathan insists on using pairs of strings to access values.

Answer (score 2):

If the Dictionary is not required for some reason, I would make your Search method as follows:

```
public IQueryable<Product> Search( Func<Product, bool> isMatch )
{
   DBDataContext dc = new DBDataContext();
   return dc.Products.Where( isMatch ).AsQueryable();
}
```

Then, you would use the method like so:

```
Obj.Search( item => item.Property1 == "Hello" && item.Property2 == "World" );
```

Is there some reason that you can't do that?

**[Edit: added AsQueryable()]**

**[Edit: for Dynamic Query using strings]**

Take a look here and see if this helps.  I haven't used it, but looks like it's what you're looking for:
http://weblogs.asp.net/scottgu/archive/2008/01/07/dynamic-linq-part-1-using-the-linq-dynamic-query-library.aspx

Personally, I would generally prefer the type-safe Expression> approach since this will give you compile time errors...but if strings are needed, then looks like the best way to do it.

Based on the above link, looks like you should be able to do:

```
query = query.Where( String.Format("{0}={1}",dict.Key,dict.Value) );
```

**[Edit: String Building Example]**

So, one of the problems is that your sql query is going to end with an AND at the end of the string but then no condition after it...so, might try changing to this...syntax might be off slightly, but should be right:

```
public IQueryable<Product> Search(Dictionary<string, string> searchParams)
{
    DBDataContext dc = new DBDataContext();

    StringBuilder sQuery = new StringBuilder();
    foreach (KeyValuePair<string, string> temp in searchParams)
    {
        if( sQuery.Length > 0 ) sQuery.Append(" AND ");
        sQuery.AppendFormat("{0}={1}",temp.Key,temp.Value);
    }

    var query = dc.Products.Where(sQuery.ToString());

    return query;
}
```

This will only use "AND" on conditions after the first.  Hope it helps...

FYI - It's off-topic, but 'why' I used StringBuilder is that string concatenation the way you had it would result in the string being destroyed and a new string being created in memory 4 times per loop...so changed to a StringBuilder since that will create a buffer that can be filled and only resized when necessary.

Comment: Your function will return `IEnumerable`, not `IQueryable`, so the code won't compile. Furthermore, rows from the database will be filtered in C# code, not in the database layer. It'll be slower and will require more memory.

Comment: Added AsQueryable() so that it should compile

Comment: Sounds like Athari knows something about the Expression<> aspect, however, that I don't...so probably best to go with his answer.

Answer (score 0):

Instead of using dictionary, you can use this method:

```
using System.Linq.Expressions;
// ...

public static IQueryable<Product> Search(Expression<Func<Product, bool>> search)
{
    DBDataContext dc = new DBDataContext();
    return dc.Products.Where(search);
}
```

You can use it like this:

```
Search(p => p.Name == "Name" && p.Id == 0);
```

You also won't be limited to string properties.

Comment: So, what you're saying is that for Linq to SQL you need to use Expression in order for it to execute the query in the DB?  Just doing Func<> will execute in C#?

Comment: This still has the same inherent limitation that I am trying to avoid. I still need to explicitly type out the property p.Name, rather than having it by dynamically generated based on whatever keys are present in the Dictionary (p.[KEY] = [VALUE]). I am in no way tied or attached to using a Dictionary, but that just seemed to me to be the only method of storing keys to search for and their values.

Comment: Okay, so the Dictionary was important...I added a link to my answer on using strings using MS Dynamic Query Library

Comment: This is the error I'm getting with that: 

"Error 1 The type arguments for method 'System.Linq.Queryable.Where<TSource>(System.Linq.IQueryable<TSource>, System.Linq.Expressions.Expression<System.Func<TSource,bool>>)' cannot be inferred from the usage. Try specifying the type arguments explicitly."

Answer (score 0):

have u try put single quote for your string?
based on your foreach loop, there will be extra 'AND' at the end of query

try this instead

```
string sQuery = searchParam.Select(entry => string.Format("{0} = '{1}'", entry.Key, entry.Value)).Aggregate((current, next) => current + " AND " next);
```

Answer (score 0):

if you are willing to create a dictionary of searchable terms than I've used something close to the approach below. I've adapted what I do be more closely fit into how you were doing things, I've also changed the names of the tables to fit a datacontext / object model that I have available to me.

The idea is to create a keyed list of terms that your query supports searching by. Then add functions that return an expression which can then be passed into the where clause of your query.

You should of course add some error handling for invalid keys etc.

```
public IQueryable<Person> Search(Dictionary<string, string> searchParams)
{
    DBDataContext dc = new DBDataContext();
    var query = dc.Persons.Where(p => true); //do an 'empty predicate' because you want 'query' to be an iqueryable<Person> not a Table<Person>

    //build a list of the types of things you can filter on.
    var criteriaDefinitions = new Dictionary<string,Func<string,Expression<Func<Person,bool>>>>();
    criteriaDefinitions.Add("FirstName",s => p => p.FirstName == s);
    criteriaDefinitions.Add("LastName",s => p => p.LastName == s);

    //you can do operations other than just equals
    criteriaDefinitions.Add("EmailContains",s => p => p.Email.Contains(s));

    //you can even create expressions that integrate joins.
    criteriaDefinitions.Add("HasContactInCity",s => p => p.Contacts.Any(c => c.City == s));


    foreach (KeyValuePair<string, string> temp in searchParams)
    {
        //grab the correct function out of the dictionary
        var func = criteriaDefinitions[temp.Key];

        //evaluating the function will return an expression which can passed into the where clause.
        var expr = func(temp.Value);
        query = query.Where(expr);
    }

    return query;
}
```

Answer (score 0):

for linq search queries multiple optional parameters
Can Use This Code:

```
var query = dx.GetAllJobs().Where(x => x.JobName.Contains(keyword));

if (SecLink != 0)
{
    query = query.Where(x => x.SectorLink.Equals(SecLink));
}

if (LocLink != 0)
{
    query = query.Where(x => x.LocationLink.Equals(LocLink));
}

if (IndLink != 0)
{
    query = query.Where(x => x.IndustryLink.Equals(IndLink));
}

if (VacLink != 0)
{
    query = query.Where(x => x.VacancyTypeLink.Equals(VacLink));
}

var lstJobs = query.ToList();
```